# EF6: Enum Types

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, enums, model-binding

There is an option in EF6 designer to convert a property to enum type. I just used this to add a new enum type to my model. How do I bind this enum to a `DropDownList` in my `FormView`?

Note: I'm using Web Forms with ASP.NET Model Binding.

Comment: Cast to int if your `value` field in DropDownList is of type integer, or simply use ToString() although not recomended for enums. But my comment may be of no use because you didn't provide any minimum implementation that might have given me an idea in what direction to start thinking

Comment: Correct, but I was expecting something more out-of-the-box since it is an EF5/6 feature. Probably there would be a way for Model Binding to detect that an entity property is of enum type so that it automatically loads the list of possible values in the control.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.GetValues` is what you are looking for I believe:

```
public enum Currency
{
    USD = 0,
    Euro,
    Frank,
    Pound
}

var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(Currency c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Currency)))
{
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = (int)c, Text = c.ToString() })
}
```

and bind to listItems...

if you deal with different enums been presented via drop down controls, you can implement a generic method that generates a bindable datasource from enum type based on following implementation of EnumToList method:

http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/enum/generic-enum-to-list-t-converter

```
public static List<SelectListItem> CreateSelectList<T>()
{
    var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach(var e in EnumToList<T>())
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = (int)e, Text = e.ToString() })
    }

    return listItems
}
```